# Why is my java code not working?

Tags: java

On the last JOptionPane, I'm trying to make the program return a dialogmessage that tells me what button the user pressed. How do I do this?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(B1)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(B1, "Player 1 pressed!");
        String[] answer = new String[3];
        answer[0] = "stein";
        answer[1] = "saks";
        answer[2] = "papir";
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "choose answer", "player 1", 0, 0, null, answer, answer[0]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 has pressed " + (what should i put here???)  );
    }
```

Comment: Give clear question... code not working means

Comment: You need to read the [ActionEvent docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html).  You can call `getSource()` to ask an event what fired it.

Comment: azurefrog, thanks for replying, could you please explain further?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?  What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @J.doe look at the answer posted...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

Get The Selected Option By:

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "choose answer", "player 1", 0, 0, null, answer, answer[0]);
```